# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectdb. MFC Application

Tags: c++, mfc, linker, linker-errors, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have following files, and errors described below: 

1- Connection.cpp

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Connection.h"
#include <libpq-fe.h>
using namespace std;

Connection::Connection()
{

}

PGconn *Connection::getConnection()
{
        const char *connStr = "dbname=Fidelity user=postgres password=home hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";
    PGconn* conn;
    conn = PQconnectdb(connStr);
   /* if(PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
          {
            cout << "\nConnection Failed.";
            PQfinish(conn);
          }
    else
          {
            cout << "\nConnection Successful\n\n";
          }*/
    return conn;
}
```

2- Main File:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataCorroborationDLL.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "Connection.h"


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
int nRetCode = 0;

HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

if (hModule != NULL)
{
    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Hello world";
                    Connection con;
        con.getConnection();
        cout <<getch();
    }
}
else
{
    // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
    _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
    nRetCode = 1;
}

return nRetCode;
}
```

I have included the "include Directory" of postgresql where it is installed and it is including the directories, and lib directory as well. It recognizes postgres commands, but not all. Now when i compile, i get this error:

Connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectdb

1>C:\Users\Irfan\Desktop\IGD\DataCorroborationDLL\Release\Tests.exe : fatal error 
LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: make sure that your linking library has reference of class PGconn!!

Comment: I included all directories. i.e include, lib, src. But it does not have any effect on it.

Comment: Have you guaranteed that all library you linking contain reference of PGconn class??

Comment: because there may be possibility that libraries that your linking not contain reference of PGconn class!!

Comment: You might see PGConn does not have any problem. PQConnectdb is not recognized. :(

Comment: yup sorry but I thing so some thing missing with PQconnectdb function linking reference!!you known if we declare a function then function body should be there!!

Comment: "Including directories" is not enough, you should tell the linker to link with library.

Comment: I meant the same as i have also included the files from Project>Properties>Linker>Add library Directories in the Visual Studio.